# jQuery code not working on iPad only

Tags: jquery, function, ipad, scroll, resize

I'm using the following code to add and remove a class when the page is loaded, resized and scrolled. It works fine on my desktop and mobile on all browsers but not my iPad 2 on any browser. The code stops all other JavaScript working on the page also. I have no idea why this is causing an issue, any help would be appreciated.

```
function gpResizeHeader() {

    if ( ! $( 'body' ).hasClass( 'gp-relative-header' ) ) {

        var mainHeaderHeight = $( '#gp-main-header' ).innerHeight();

        if ( $( '#gp-top-header' ).length > 0 ) {
            var topHeaderHeight = $( '#gp-top-header' ).innerHeight();
        } else {
            var topHeaderHeight = 1;
        }

        if ( $( '#wpadminbar' ).length > 0 ) {
            var adminBar = $( '#wpadminbar' ).innerHeight();
        } else {
            var adminBar = 0;
        }

        $( '#gp-fixed-header-padding' ).height( mainHeaderHeight + topHeaderHeight );

        function gpScrollingHeader() {
            if ( $( window ).width() = ( topHeaderHeight + adminBar ) ) {
                    $( 'body' ).addClass( 'gp-mobile-scrolling' ).removeClass( 'gp-desktop-scrolling' );
                } else {
                    $( 'body' ).removeClass( 'gp-mobile-scrolling' );
                }
            } else if ( $( window ).width() = topHeaderHeight ) {
                    $( 'body' ).addClass( 'gp-mobile-scrolling' ).removeClass( 'gp-desktop-scrolling' );
                } else {
                    $( 'body' ).removeClass( 'gp-mobile-scrolling' );
                }
            } else if ( $( window ).width() > 1082 ) {  
                if ( $( document ).scrollTop() >= topHeaderHeight ) {
                    $( 'body' ).addClass( 'gp-desktop-scrolling' ).removeClass( 'gp-mobile-scrolling' );
                } else {
                    $( 'body' ).removeClass( 'gp-desktop-scrolling' );
                }
            }           
        }
        gpScrollingHeader();
        $( window ).scroll( gpScrollingHeader );

    }

}

gpResizeHeader();
$( window ).resize( gpResizeHeader );
```